# How to use DryIoC in ASP.Net WebForms Application?

Tags: dryioc

I would like to have some basic sample how to use DryIoC for WebForms application with BasePage (base for all pages) and IRepository and Repository for connection with database (via NHibernate)

At the moment it is made using application property containing NHibernate session. I would like to make it with DryIoC in order to use Repository for database operation everywhere . What is the best way for that?

Comment: Please  provide a code sample of how it is used now using some stub interfaces and implementations. And what do you want to achieve in principal. It will help to pinpoint exact problem and provide an adequate answer to you.